# Problems configuring server

Tags: node.js, server, get, postman

I'm just learning how to use Node.JS and I'm trying to set up an express server, but when I try to test the route and do the `GET` request in Postman it throws an error. What is wrong with my code below?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const logger = require("morgan");
const cors = requiere("cors");


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

app.disable("x-powered-by");

app.set("port", port);

server.listen(3000, "192.168.1.36" || "localhost", function() {
console.log("aplicacion de NodeJS " + port +" iniciada...")
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.send("Ruta raíz del backend");
});

// ERROR HANDLER
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
console.log(err);
res.status(err.status || 500).send(err.stack);
});
```

What Postman tells me does not clarify much where the error is:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you made a typo here `requiere("cors")` it must be require and also you must import express `const express = require('express')`

Comment: I am sharing the code I corrected and running below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you made a typo here `requiere("cors")` it must be `require` and also you must import express `const express = require('express')`

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const logger = require("morgan");


const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("aplicacion de NodeJS " + port + " iniciada...")
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Ruta raíz del backend");
});
```